# how to decode this request

Tags: encoding, url

I need help for this. I got a request but I don't know what can I do:

```
GET http://localhost/xor.php?plaintext=cipher=%00%00%1D%10%1A,%06%05%16%16%0D%12%0B%3A9%5DRT%06YVD HTTP/1.1
```

Full request : `https://imgur.com/w9tvNee`

I already tried with url decode for decode at the `cipher=...` but i got nothing interesting.

i got new on this request i got in plaintext= `jenesuispasleflag1337` so that gives

`http://localhost/xor.php?plaintext=jenesuispasleflag1337&cipher=%00%00%1D%10%1A,%06%05%16%16%0D%12%0B%3A9%5DRT%06YVD HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Based on the the parameter names of the request, I wonder if it is not only encoded but also encrypted.

Comment: If you want ppl to help you diagnose your xor.php that belongs to you, you should post this question under stackoverflow with the source.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like percent-encoded Unicode strings. Taking a rough pass at the string just based on sight: it looks like there are two strings that are comma separated.

The first string: `%00%00%1D%10%1A` starts with two null bytes, which is probably why your decoder isn't working: it's very likely stopping processing at the null bytes since most systems interpret that as an "end of data" marker by default.

Decoding back to the characters themselves gets you a mix of printable and non-printable chars:

```
,
:9]RTYVD
```

Comment: Without the code, I doubt it is the case.